# How the read/write capacity is increased/decreased with amazon keyspaces provisioned capacity and application auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-keyspaces

Say when we create a Table in amazon keyspaces with **provisioned capacity mode** and **application auto scaling enabled** with min read capacity as 100 RCU and max read capacity as 1000 RCU with utilization rate of 70%

1. what is the RCU table is created with ?
2. when is the RCU increased ?
3. when is the RCU decreased ?
4. will the RCU ever cross beyond 1000 RCU with auto scaling ?
5. if the load cross beyond what 1000 RCU can handle what is the error encountered ?
6. if there is no load/traffic what is the cost charged ?

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/autoscaling.html

Answer (score 2):

1. It created with whatever you provision directly on the table, but before it goes active it'll sync with autoscaling a become 100 in your case.
2. When you exceed 70% of your provisioned capacity for 2 consecutive minutes.
3. When you are below your 70% threshold and a 20% buffer for 15 consecutive minutes.
4. No, burst capacity could let you consume more, but the tables provisioned capacity will not allow the table go beyond the max, meaning you'll never be charged more.
5. ProvisionedThroughputExceededException
6. 100 RCU as that's your min.